# finding the shortest path in a graph from start to end vertex

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I am trying to find the shortest path among all possible paths in a graph. I wrote the below program, and when I try to search path from vertex 'A' to 'D', it returns ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']. But the shortest distance is ['A', 'B', 'D']. Is there a way to find it given that I have already found all the possible nodes?

```
from collections import defaultdict


def find_path(graph,start,end,path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    print "intermediate", path
    if start == end:
        return path
    if not graph.has_key(start):
        return None
    for node in graph[start]:
        print "node",node
        if node[1] not in path:
            newpath = find_path(graph,node[1],end,path)
            if newpath :
                return newpath
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    graph = defaultdict(list)
    graph = { 
            'A': [('A','B'),('A','C')],
            'B' : [('B','C'),('B','D')],
            'C' : [('C','D')],
            'D' : [('D','C')],
            'E' : [('E','F')],
            'F' : [('F','C')]
            }

    path = find_path(graph,'A','D')
```

Comment: Your code nowhere checks the length of a path, or keeps a record of the shortest path so far, or continues to try finding paths after finding one path.  You'll need to do most of those.

Comment: Read about adjacency lists and Djikstra's shortest path algorithm for a graph.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorthim is one option that you may want to look at.  Some sample code can be found here: http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_Dijkstras_Shortest_Path_Algorithm.php

Comment: Downvoted :( Let me try doing something about the tracking of paths

Answer (score 0):

I have now added a new function, which is typically a greedy algorithm. It closes the recursion, if its sees a node connected to 'end' node. Thanks @Jonathan for your advice. Will appreciate any criticism towards this approach.

```
def shortest_path(graph,start,end,short_path=[]):
    short_path = short_path + [start]
    #print "Initial short path",short_path
    if start == end:
        return short_path
    if not graph.has_key(start):
        return None
    for node in graph[start]:
        #print "short node",graph[start]
        vend = [x[1] for x in graph[start] if x[1] == end]
        print "v_end",vend
        if vend :
            if vend[0] == end:
                #print "printing end nodes",vend,start
                tmp_path = shortest_path(graph,end,end,short_path)
                if tmp_path:
                    #print "shortest intermediate path",tmp_path
                    return tmp_path

        elif node[1] not in short_path:
            tmp_path = shortest_path(graph,node[1],end,short_path)
            #print tmp_path, "start",node[1], "end",end
            if tmp_path:
                #print "shortest intermediate",tmp_path
                return tmp_path
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: That's not going to work. It'll jump to the end node if it gets within 1 link of it, but it still doesn't care about how long a path it takes to get within 1 link of the end node.